# Tell JavaScript my array is sorted when searching for an element

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I know is sorted by one of the object properties. I want to look in the array for the object with that property equalling a specific value, so I do this:

```
arrOfObjects.find((obj) => obj.property === value)
```

However, this is an `O(n)` operation for an unsorted array, but `O(log n)` using binary search on sorted arrays.

Is there any way to tell JavaScript my array is sorted when doing a `.find()`, or do I have to manually implement a binary search?

Comment: No, there's no way to give `find` that information.

Comment: You'll have to implement binary search. Depending on your needs, you can consider making `arrOfObjects` a `Map`, keyed by `obj.property`. Then you get constant access.

Comment: you'll have to write a manual search for that as `find` is `O(n)`

Comment: Regardless, checking if the array is sorted is `O(n)` so you've always got that time complexity, might just stick with `.find` unless there's a `sorted` flag after a sorting method is called.

Comment: If you want to perform a binary search, an array is a sub-optimal data structure, you should instead be using an object.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in binary search functionality in JavaScript.

Even if there was [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) itself cannot benefit from it, since it expects a callback that returns `true` or `false`. There is no way to determine if the expected result is *before* or *after* a given point based on a boolean result which only indicates a match.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a protoype of `Array`, like

```
Array.prototype.binaryFind = function (callbackFn, thisArg) {
    // code
};
```

Then you need to specify a function as callback which has three states to determin the find, left or right side. An idea is to take the same approach like for sorting where an value takes the order, depending of negative, zero or positive which shows the relation of the values.

```
function findInObjects(key, value) {
    return function (object, index, array) { // 
        if (object[key] === value) return 0;
        if (object[key] < value) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```